# How to raise an HTTP 400 in a model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

My route:

```
@router.get('/check/{value}', status_code=200)
def ranks_check(value: BasicInput = Depends()):
    """
    Test endpoint
    """

    return value
```

My model:

```
class BasicInput:
    """
    Get Confidence to score Input class
    """

    value: int

    @validator('value')
    def check_if_value_in_range(cls, v):
        if not 0 < v < 1000001:
            raise ValueError('Value Exceeded Limit')
```

What I need to do:

I need to validate the input and raise an HTTP 400 if there is a ValueError.

I know I could have done the integer validation using Pydantic's `Field` types and do the run `check_if_value_in_range` in the route function itself. I am looking for a solution using the model.

Comment: It does not return anything. I added a return statement to the validator function but No changes.

Answer (score 9):

See the FastAPI docs on [Raise an HTTPException in your code](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code):

> `HTTPException` is a normal Python exception with additional data relevant for APIs.
>
> Because it's a Python exception, you don't `return` it, you `raise` it.
>
> This also means that if you are inside a utility function that you are calling inside of your *path operation function*, and you raise the `HTTPException` from inside of that utility function, it won't run the rest of the code in the *path operation function*, it will terminate that request right away and send the HTTP error from the `HTTPException` to the client.

```
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException

class BasicInput(BaseModel):
    value: int

    @validator("value")
    def check_if_value_in_range(cls, v):
        if not 0 < v < 1000001:
            # raise ValueError("Value Exceeded Limit")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="value exceeded limit")

        return v
```

```
$ curl -i -XGET localhost:8000/check/1000002
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...

{"detail":"value exceeded limit"}

$ curl -i -XGET localhost:8000/check/42
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

{"value":42}
```

But for that to work, there are some things in your current code that needs to be fixed:

1. If you are using Pydantic's [validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) decorator, then your class needs to either be a Pydantic `BaseModel` or [a Pydantic `dataclass`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#dataclass-validators).

   ```
   class BasicInput(BaseModel):  # <--------------------
       value: int
   ```

   If you also add a `print` statement or a breakpoint on your `validator` function, you'll see that **it's actually never called**, since it's not a Pydantic `BaseModel`.
2. The validator function is missing handling for the case when the `if` condition is `False` (when `v` is valid inside the range). From the Pydantic docs:

   > validators should either return the parsed value or raise a `ValueError`, `TypeError`, or `AssertionError` (`assert` statements may be used).

   ```
   class BasicInput(BaseModel):
       value: int

       @validator("value")
       def check_if_value_in_range(cls, v):
           if not 0 < v < 1000001:
               raise ValueError("Value Exceeded Limit")

           # v is good
           return v  # <--------------------
   ```

In your original code, you [mentioned that you were getting "nothing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770979/fastapi-model-validation#comment121538305_68770979). I assume you were getting an empty `{}` response for both valid and invalid `value`s:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/check/42
{}

$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/check/1000002
{}
```

This is because in the route function, `value` is the `BasicInput` class, **it's not the `{value}` path value or the `BasicInput.value` integer value**.

```
@router.get("/check/{value}", status_code=200)
def ranks_check(value: BasicInput = Depends()):
    print(type(value))  # <class 'main.BasicInput'>
    return value
```

What you are *actually* getting as "empty" response is the result of FastAPI applying its [jsonable_encoder](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/) to the `BasicInput` class. When FastAPI gets to the `return value` on your route function, it will use `jsonable_encoder` to convert it to a `JSONResponse`. See the docs on [Return a Response Directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/).

Internally, since `BasicInput` is not a Pydantic `BaseModel` or an iterable (ex. a `dict`-like object), it results in an empty dict `{}`. (You can check the [code for `jsonable_encoder`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/25a48287ed6043f7ee81417cef3c4d1f1dc56f72/fastapi/encoders.py#L29), but it's because of `dict(obj)` and `vars(obj)`).

So, as mentioned in [MatsLindh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68772198/2745495), models used in a FastAPI request/response context typically subclass from Pydantic `BaseModel`, and after subclassing it properly, you should now get non-empty responses:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/check/42
{"value":42}

$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/check/1000002
Internal Server Error
   
...
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for BasicInput
value
    Value Exceeded Limit (type=value_error)
```

Once that's fixed, simply follow the guide in FastAPI's [Raise an HTTPException in your code](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code) (as I mentioned at the start of this answer) to raise the HTTP error directly from the model.

But I agree with [MatsLindh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770979/fastapi-model-validation#comment121540030_68772198), that this is not a "good" practice, as it violates the **SRP**/[Single Responsibility Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17100). Your model is doing 2 things: validating your inputs *and* raising the appropriate HTTP error response.

FastAPI is supposed to handle your requests and responses, while Pydantic is supposed to represent your models and data. You let FastAPI accept the request, pass it to Pydantic to validate and store the model data, then let FastAPI convert the result to the appropriate response. Your intended solution is also confusing because for valid/success cases, it's handled in the route function but for invalid/error cases, it's handled in the model validation function.

FastAPI already knows how to catch Pydantic `ValidationError`'s and convert them to the appropriate HTTP error responses. In this case, FastAPI returns an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

If the purpose is to provide model-specific error responses, you should keep the `raise ValueError` on your models and then override FastAPI's default validation error handlers. See the section on [Override the default exception handlers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-the-default-exception-handlers).

Here's my recommended code:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.exceptions import ValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

# MODELS

class BasicInput(BaseModel):
    value: int

    @validator("value")
    def check_if_value_in_range(cls, v):
        if not 0 < v < 1000001:
            raise ValueError("Value Exceeded Limit")

        return v

# VIEWS

api = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()

@api.exception_handler(ValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc: ValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content={"error": str(exc)})

@router.get("/check/{value}")
def ranks_check(value: BasicInput = Depends()):
    return value

api.include_router(router)
```

```
$ curl -i -XGET localhost:8000/check/42
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

{"value":42}

$ curl -i -XGET localhost:8000/check/1000002
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...

{"error":"1 validation error for BasicInput\nvalue\n  Value Exceeded Limit (type=value_error)"}
```

Comment: If in the above model we have a field called `text` and I want to ensure that the number of lines in the text is not more than say 100 lines. I can check that by using the @validator decorator and a method like you mentioned above. Now if I want to return a custom HTTP 413 error, using the `validation_exception_handler` method won't work for me as it sends a generic 400 error. If I throw a ValueError in my validation method, how will ValidationError or RequestValidationError know that I want to throw a 413? I am raising HTTPException from within my model now, and it breaking the SRP.

Comment: What error should I throw in my model class so that when it propagates to the FastAPI request validation error handler, I will be able to send the right error to my client? The only thing I can think of now is to move the validation logic out of my model class to the path function and raise the HTTP Exception with 413 there. It feels weird to do validation in path function though. BTW, thanks for the answer above, very clear and logically explained.

Comment: I figured out what error I should throw in my model class so that it propagates to the FastAPI request validation error handler. It was in the Pydantic [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling). The second part of my question still remains, how will `validation_exception_handler` know to throw 413 on the error as I have many other types of validation errors that could be thrown and each can have their own HTTP error code that needs to be sent to the client.

Comment: @Raqib Not sure if this is the best approach (as I don't have a similar use-case in my projects), but you could create a custom `CustomValueError` that subclasses from `ValueError`, then just add an extra field to indicate the error type (ex.  maybe an enum `error_type`). Then, in FastAPI's `validation_exception_handler`, the passed `exc` `ValidationError` object will contain a `ctx` field that contains any extra fields that FastAPI did not use from the raised `ValueError` (`exc.errors()[0]['ctx']`). At that point, you can get that `ctx` and set the appropriate status code.

Comment: @Raqib I suggest posting a _separate_ question for your issue, as it's more of a follow-up question from this Q&A pairs. That would make it a lot easier to explain, rather than down here in the comments (and possibly other people might have a better idea).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did something similar, just wanted to know what is the elegant way of doing this. I will create a separate post to follow up on the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're not inheriting from `BaseModel` in your example, but there is there is no need for a custom validator to do what you want to do. You can use one of the constrained types in FastAPI:

```
from pydantic import conint

class BasicInput(BaseModel):
    """
    Get Confidence to score Input class
    """

    value: conint(gt=0, le=1000000)
```

Or you can use the Field class:

```
class BasicInput(BaseModel):
    value: int = Field(..., gt=0, le=1000000)
```

In both cases you should always inherit from `BaseModel`. I'd also recommend using a better input model name than `BasicModel`. From your view comment it seems like `ApplicationInformationRequest` or something similar could be more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, I will use a Better Input Model Name. Thank you.

Comment: How do I raise HTTP Exceptions from the Model?

Comment: Why do you need to raise an HTTP exception from the model? FastAPI will do that for you if the value doesn't fit within the requirement.